# find() removes the immediate tag from my HTML stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this HTML

```
<div id='add_more_edu'>
 <div class='one_exp'>
    --- many INPUT and SELECT elements with disabled attribute
 </div>
</div>
```

And I have a Button on my page, when clicked, a function is called, that function's code looks like this.

```
var edu_contect = $("#add_more_edu").clone().html();

// Line # 2        
edu_contect = $(edu_contect).find("input,select").removeAttr('disabled');

$('.edu_history_div').append(edu_contect);
```

The fields get disabled successfully but the content which I get appended in  `.edu_history_div` is like so

```
<div id='add_more_edu'>

    --- many INPUT and SELECT elements with disabled attribute

</div>
```

The `<div class='one_exp'>` gets disappear.

If I comment `Line # 2` then `<div class='one_exp'>` DOES NOT disappear.

What is the solution?

Or

any alternative to this line
`edu_contect = $(edu_contect).find("input,select").removeAttr('disabled');`???

I have tried

`$(edu_contect).find("input,select").removeAttr('disabled');`

and `<div class='one_exp'>` is okay but the `Disabled` attribute is not removed from `input` and `select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `find()` on `$(edu_contect)` returns just the matching elements which in your case are input and select and these are stored in `edu_contect` on the line `edu_contect = ...`.

Also, `html()` is not required here, as `append()` and other operations like `find()` can be performed on the object returned by `.clone()`.

Use the following

```
var edu_contect = $("#add_more_edu").clone();
edu_contect.find("input,select").removeAttr('disabled')
$('.edu_history_div').append(edu_contect);
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lufv3x39/)**

Comment: That is perfect ... works .... but please explain logice behind you removed `.html()` and used `edu_contect` instead of `$(edu_contect)`

Comment: `edu_contect = $(edu_contect).find()...` saves/assigns only the found elements in  `edu_contect`. And as `html()`  is not required when you need to append cloned element, I removed `$()` from `edu_contect`